# String.compareTo() vs String.matches() in Java Performance

Tags: java, string, string-comparison

Are there any advantage of one of the methods over the other when comparing Strings?

Comment: What results did your measurements show?

Comment: With today's processors performance is not an issue..Focus on your business logic.. **Don't** waste your time doing unnecessary optimizations..Plzz.

Comment: @Henry, I just want to compare Strings to proceed with my business logic. It doesn't matter if I handle it using ==0 for compareTo or boolean checking for matches.

Comment: @Anirudh, It is not about wasting time. I am trying to build a high performance application that parses hundreds of thousands of XMLs so every milli second optimization counts. The current application doing the same job takes 8 hours although it runs on a high end machine.

Comment: @elven_rider hmm...so you should try both on those xml's and see the difference!..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Not tested with data set** but checking to the source codes of [compareTo](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/lang/String.java#String.compareTo%28java.lang.String%29) and [matches](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/lang/String.java#String.matches%28java.lang.String%29)
 it seems `compareTo` would be faster as `matches` then again calls [Pattern.matches](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/regex/Pattern.java#Pattern.matches%28java.lang.String,java.lang.CharSequence%29) and includes other function calls as well (since `matches` takes regex as input - regex compilation puts extra overhead.

Though since `matches` accepts regex as well it has his its own plus points

Answer (score 0):

A difference is that

```
x.equals((String)null)
```

returns `false` while

```
x.compareTo((String)null) == 0
```

throws a `NullPointerException`. So they are not always interchangeable even for Strings.

you can find [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kirillosenkov/archive/2010/09/22/what-s-faster-string-equals-or-string-compare.aspx) what's the better performance

```
string stringToTest = "Hello";
stringToTest.Equals("hello", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
```

Equals Time: 00:00:00.0009247

```
String.Compare(stringToTest, "hello", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
```

Compare Timer: 00:00:00.0000012

you can check in java with

```
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.*;
public class HelloWorld{

     public static void main(String []args){

      String Str1 = new String("This is really not immutable!!");
      String Str2 = Str1;
      String Str3 = new String("This is really not immutable!!");
      boolean retVal;
      long millis = System.nanoTime();
      retVal = Str1.equals( Str2 );
      System.out.println("Returned Value = " + retVal );

      retVal = Str1.equals( Str3 );
      System.out.println("Returned Value = " + retVal );
      long millis1 = System.nanoTime();

      System.out.println("time to equals " + (millis1-millis) );
      int ret = Str1.compareTo( Str2 );
      System.out.println("Returned Value = " + ret );

      ret = Str1.compareTo( Str3 );
      System.out.println("Returned Value = " + ret );      
        System.out.println("Hello World");
        Date d2 = new Date();

       long millis2 = System.nanoTime();

       System.out.println("time to compareTo " + (millis2-millis1) );
     }
}
```

and get the output:

```
Returned Value = true
Returned Value = true
time to equals 189893
Returned Value = 0
Returned Value = 0
Hello World
time to compareTo 692090
```

so yeah, equals seems to be faster

Comment: the reference you have taken is of C#..does same happens with java as well ? as OP is asking in reference to java

Comment: well the equals and comapreTo gives the output that you gave :)

Comment: @sansix indeed it does

Comment: yeah just checked in their source codes why they returns those kinda outputs

Comment: Hello "No Idea For Name", I was asking about String.matches() and not String.equals(). Are they the same?